# how to remove field in logstash output

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration, elk

I have set up an ELK stack. For the logstash instance, it has two output including Kafka and elasticsearch.

For the output of elasticsearch, I want to keep the field @timestamp. For the output of Kafka, I want to remove the field @timestamp. So I cannot just remove field @timestamp in the filter. I just want it removed for the Kafka output.

I have not found this kind of solution.

### append

Try to use clone plugin:

```
clone {
  clones => ["kafka"]
  id => ["kafka"]
  remove_field => ["@timestamp"]
}

output {

if [type] != "kafka" {
  elastcsearch output
}

if [type] == "kafka" {
  kafka output
}
}
```

It's strange that the output of elasticsearch can work. But it cannot output to kafka. And I have tried to judge by id, still does not wordk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only remove fields in the `filter` block, to have the same pipeline output two different versions of the same event you will need to clone your events, remove the field in the cloned event and use conditionals in the output.

To clone your event and remove the `@timestamp` field you will need something like this in your `filter` block.

```
filter {
    # your other filters
    #
    clone {
        clones => ["kafka"]
    }
    if [type] == "kafka" {
        mutate {
            remove_field => ["@timestamp"]
        }
    }
}
```

This will clone the event and the cloned event will have the value `kafka` in the field `type`, you will then use this field in the conditionals in your output.

```
output {
    if [type] != "kafka" {
        your elasticsearch output
    }
    if [type] == "kafka" {
        your kafka output
    }
}
```

Comment: It's so strange. The type judgement only works for elasticsearch output but not for kafka output. I even tried to set id of clone plugin. But it doesn't work either.

Comment: It's my mistake. I remove the field `type` which leads to the type invalidate. But I still wonder how to judge by `id`.